# Sort MS Word paragraphs alphabetically with Python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, ms-word, python-docx

How can i sort MS Word paragraphs alphabetically with python-docx ?

I tried several things but can't get it working.
Is somethings like this code bellow could do the work ?

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()
document.add_paragraph('B - paragraph two' )
document.add_paragraph('A - paragraph one' )

document.paragraphs.sort(key=lambda x: x.text)

document.save('sorted_paragraphs.docx')
```

Expected result in `sorted_paragraphs.docx`:

```
A - paragraph one
B - paragraph two
```

ie: Is there a way to do the same things that [MS word GUI sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKlyQ.png) does with python ?

The point is to change the position of the paragraphs in the document so they are displayed in alphabetical order based on the paragraphs first letter.

Comment: I assume there is a missing `import ....` at the beginning of your code? Otherwise I'd just get `NameError: name 'Document' is not defined`

Comment: Indeed, i edited my question. You will need to `pip3 install python-docx` too.

Comment: Do you actually want to change the position of the paragraphs in the document? Or do you just want to process the paragraphs in alphabetical order?

Comment: @scanny, Yes, i do want to change the position of the paragraphs in the document so they are displayed in alphabetical order based on the paragraph first letter (i edited my question for clarity, thx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
# --- range of paragraphs you want to sort, by paragraph index
# --- note that the last paragraph (18) is not included, consistent
# --- with Python "slice" notation.
start, end = 8, 18

# --- create a sorted list of tuples (pairs) of paragraph-text (the
# --- basis for the sort) and the paragraph `<w:p>` element for each
# --- paragraph in range.
text_element_triples = sorted(
    (paragraph.text, i, paragraph._p)
    for i, paragraph in enumerate(document.paragraphs[start:end])
)

# --- move each paragraph element into the sorted position, starting
# --- with the first one in the list
_, _, last_p = text_element_triples[0]

for _, _, p in text_element_triples[1:]:
    last_p.addnext(p)
    last_p = p
```

Comment: This is working with most of files, thx. Howerver i got an error from time to time 'sorted((paragraph.text, paragraph._p) for paragraph in doc.paragraphs[start:end])
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'CT_P' and 'CT_P'', all files are generated the same way so i don't get why it's not 100% effective.

Comment: Okay, I made a small change that I think will fix this. The problem would arise when the text of two paragraphs matched exactly. In that case, the sort algorithm would attempt to order the `<w:p>` elements (`CT_P` objects) to "break the tie". It appears that the elements are not orderable. Inserting the index of the paragraph fixes this because it is both comparable and always unique, so `w:p` elements are never compared.